# Anooying persistent text middle of screen Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-20.04

I cannot get rid of this text strip you can see in black color. It's a path from terminal which has stayed on screen even after closing the terminal. This issue is very frequent and goes away after I reboot. Is there anyone who had the same issue and was able to resolve it?[image: The black strip containing text does not goes away]

Answer (score 0):

For this you just need to reload the GUI. For this you can do:

1. `alt + f2`
2. Put **'r'** in the input box and press enter.
3. This will solve the issue.